# Check if the lines in the dataframe roughly correspond to each other

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, nlp

I have a data frame with names of cities in Morocco and another one with similar names but that was not well coded. Here's the first one:

```
>>> df[['new_regiononame']].head()

    new_regiononame
0   Grand Casablanca-Settat
1   Fès-Meknès
2   Souss-Massa
3   Laayoune-Sakia El Hamra
4   Fès-Meknès
```

and here's the other one I wanted to change to the names of the first one. At least they know a way to read it correctly:

```
>>>X_train[['S02Q03A_Region']].head()

    S02Q03A_Region
10918   FÃ¨s-MeknÃ¨s
1892    Rabat-SalÃ©-KÃ©nitra
6671    Casablanca-Settat
4837    Marrakech-Safi
6767    Casablanca-Settat
```

How can I check if the lines in the dataframe roughly correspond to each other and, if so, rename `X_train` rows by `df` ones?

So far I only know how to extract which rows in `X_train` have exact equivalents in `df`:

```
X_train['S02Q03A_Region'][X_train['S02Q03A_Region'].isin(df['new_regiononame'].unique())]
```

Comment: Question: By renaming the rows, do you mean that the city names in `X_train` are not listed as exactly the same as `df` but there is a large degree of similarity? For example: `FÃ¨s-MeknÃ¨s` in `df` corresponds to `FÃ¨s-MeknÃ¨s` in `X_train` ?

Comment: @RahulP `Fès-Meknès` but yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) could do the job here.

The Levenshtein distance gives you the distance between two words by calculating the number of single character edits that are needed to convert one word to the other. You could establish a reasonable threshold comparing one dataframe column to the other such as:

1. If it starts with the same character (?)
2. If the difference between
   lengths of the city names is only `x` characters apart?
3. If the Levenshtein distance is less than `y`

etc. etc.

The code to calculate Levenshtein distance is:

```
import nltk
nltk.edit_distance("FÃ¨s-MeknÃ¨s", "Fès-Meknès")
```

Output:

```
4
```